# Adding independent fill and alpha aesthetics with `geom_histogram()`

Tags: r, ggplot2, alpha

I sometimes think it's useful to have an `alpha` dimension as well as a color/fill dimension in a plot. In **ggplot2**, it's pretty natural to do this with `geom_point`, but I'm struggling to map the `alpha` aesthetic using `geom_histogram`. Is it possible to create a histogram where parts of each bar are colored (with `fill` aesthetic) according to one variable, and made transparent (perhaps with an `alpha` aesthetic) according to a different one?

```
library(tidyverse)

# different color and alpha can be done easily with geom_point
mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = wt, y = mpg, color = as.factor(gear), alpha = cyl)) +
  geom_point()


# not happening with geom_histogram
mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = wt, fill = as.factor(gear), alpha = cyl)) +
  geom_histogram()
```

Thanks!!

**EDIT**
This seems like a step in the right direction:

```
mtcars %>% 
  mutate(cyl_gear = paste(cyl, gear, sep = "_")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = wt, fill = cyl_gear, color = as.factor(cyl))) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = 
                      sort(unlist(map(1:n_distinct(mtcars$gear)
                                 , function(ge){hcl.colors(n_distinct(mtcars$cyl), alpha = ge/n_distinct(mtcars$gear))})))) +
  scale_color_manual(values = sort(hcl.colors(n_distinct(mtcars$cyl)))) +
  geom_histogram()
```

To be complete, I would accommodate arbitrary numeric alpha values given by the data.

Comment: How would that work? Histograms bins results. There's not just one `cyl` value per bin. Did you want to use the mean value or something?

Comment: This may be the issue... because I am using the default stacked position, it *looks* like there's more than one `gear` value per bin... I am looking for a way to track those data despite the binning which is perhaps asking too much...

Comment: Perhaps what I'm seeking is a nice way to pass alpha and RGB components to the `fill` aesthetic, programmatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to do this by assigning one variable to `fill`, one variable to `alpha`, and a grouping variable comprising the interaction of the two. In this grouping, the `alpha` variable should be listed first so that colors group together within bars.

```r
mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = wt, fill = factor(gear), alpha = cyl, 
             group = interaction(cyl, gear))) +
  geom_histogram()
```

[image]

Comment: This is just what I was looking for, thanks! Note: `alpha` variable proceeds `fill` to get colors to group together before shades. This is still the case if the arguments to `aes` are presented in reverse: 
`mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = wt
             , alpha = cyl
             , fill = factor(gear)
             , group = interaction(cyl, gear))) +
  geom_histogram()`